# Fixing zero value position on x axis when using thousand separator in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use thousand separator on x axis in ggplot, but I noticed that position of zero value has also changed and I do not know why. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Here is my data:

```
x <- seq(1000000,70000000, by=1000000)
y <- c(1:70)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(size=1, col="blue") +
scale_x_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE))
```

This is my plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather raw solution:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(size=1, col="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=function(x) {
    sapply(x, function(x) {
      print(str(x))
      if (!is.na(x) & x>0) {
        format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)
      } else {
        "0"
      }
    })
  }
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `breaks` option of the `scale_x_continuous()` ,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(size=1, col="blue") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", 
                                               scientific = FALSE),
                                              breaks = c(1000000,20000000,40000000,60000000))
```

gives,

[image]